# What are the most effective ways of learning vocabulary of any language?

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, vocabulary

Vocabulary is the most important thing to become enriched in a language in my perspective. But for most of the  adult learners of a language, memorization process sometimes seems very boring and hard too. So now the question is what are the most effective ways of learning vocabulary of any language? Please share tips & tricks on how to build a solid vocabulary stack.

Comment: That depends on how you define **effective**.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of methods to build up vocabulary I could find. I have created a important list of them here.

1. **Read a lot** : Read stories, newspapers, articles a lot. Have a dictionary in the side and look the meaning for words you don't know.
2. **Use mnemonics** : Use specialised memory tricks that can suite you to keep the words in memory.
3. **Study it in context** : Once you have learned a word try to use it in sentences.

> We don’t communicate using individual words, we communicate with
>   phrases and sentences.

4. **Use pictures** : When learning a word try to associate itself with a picture.
5. **Listen while you read** : Get an audio book and a book on the language you want to learn. Listen to the audio book while reading.
6. **Embed your new language into your life and into your daily routine** : Try using the words you learned in your shopping list, etc... If possible speak to a native person of that language.

For additional reference:

1. [Experts reveal favourite methods learning vocabulary - smartlanguagelearner.com](https://www.smartlanguagelearner.com/experts-reveal-method-learning-vocabulary/)
2. [Ten beat vocabulary learning tips](http://www.sheppardsoftware.com/vocabulary_tips.htm)