# What are the most effective ways for learning to write in a language?

Tags: resource-request, writing

I have been learning from Duolingo, where I can learn by reciting, hearing and typing.

**However, I want to learn to write the language. So, what are the effective ways for doing it?**

And, are there any online sites which help me with that too?  Like for example, for learning and writing Chinese, etc?

By effective, I mean in a way which helps the learner retain the knowledge better and longer.

Comment: @fi12 I used `French`  just for an example of how Duolingo works!  `Chinese` is the main focus of the qn.  Effective means `in a way which helps the learner retain the knowledge better and longer` :)

Comment: Then please make necessary edits to your question to clarify that for any future visitors.

Comment: @fi12 Why should we narrow down questions to one language? Aren't we supposed to have questions that are general for multiple langauges?

Comment: Please do *not* narrow the scope to one language! Mentioning the language(s) you're trying to learn is good, but if your question is specific only to one language, it will probably make it off-topic here.  Defining "effective" is important, however. The best way to make this a good question in my opinion, is to identify a specific problem you're having.  *Specific* is the key word here.

Comment: So it sounds like you're trying to learn *hand writing* (as opposed to, say, typing)?  That's important to clarify, I'd say.

Comment: Learning to write Chinese or another logographic writing system will probably be different from learning an alphabet, so I don't think narrowing to at least "logographic" languages would be a bad thing.

Comment: @Flimzy, let me clarify. I meant that it should be narrowed down to one language group. As Hatchet says, a question about logographic languages would have drastically different answers from a question about Romance languages. Agreed, you should keep the question relatable to all questions, my mistake.

Comment: Related: http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/646/writing-fluently?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

On my opinion, based on Language Learning Theory, the best way to learn "how to write" is reading. The more you read, the more you can write. Of course, is the same for speak: The more you listening, the more you can speak.

However, languages with use different alphabets possibly will need some training for write the different lyrics.

And about sites, it's really difficult to tell you because that can vary depending of the Language.

For example, have tons of sites and courses about english, but lacks about Japanese.

And for retain the knowledge, I recommend you to search about "Spacing Memorization Theory" / "Spaced Repetition", and try to apply it in yours studies. Anki is a good app for that.

Comment: Reading doesn't teach you important things such as stroke order: it's going to teach you how to write about as much as watching the Super Bowl is going to teach you how to play football. The best way to learn how to do something is to do it. Practice makes perfect, or so I've heard.

Comment: You are correct when  you say that reading don't teach you a stroke order. I said this on "...languages with use different alphabets possibly will need some training..."

But, for example, why are you learning a stroke order of a Kanji if you don't know how to use them?

That's mentioned too in the Input Hypothesis (By: Stephen Krashen), and soo, you can talk to any linguist about the importance of reading, or just search it.

And don't compare physical activities with mental activities, it's pretty obvious that you can't learn how to play football watching Super Bowl.